# How to retrieve posted data via FacesContext

Tags: jsf, postdata, facescontext

I'm making the following curl request to a legacy JSF application:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: text/plain" -X POST \
-d '{"name":"value"}' http://localhost:8080/aaa/bbb
```

The problem I'm having is I don't know how to retrieve the posted JSON data from the FacesContext as a raw String.

I've tried the following:

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()`

and this returns an empty map, which I'm assuming is because the posted data is not keyed to a parameter name.

If I debug with the following:

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestContentLength()`

I get the correct data length, i.e. 16

If I debug with the following:

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestContentType()`

I get the correct type, i.e. text/plain.

But what I can't work out is how to actually retrieve the posted data itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `getReader()` method of the `HttpServletRequest` class to obtain a `BufferedReader` that'll allow you to read the POST content data.

```
((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getReader()
```